# How to find the smallest and largest element in an array of random integers?

Tags: java, arrays

Hi guys I'm writing a program to do the thing below. I can't figure out how to write it. I've only figured out how to do generate the random ints but other than that I'm completely lost. I would love it if you guys help me!
program that creates an array of size 10, and fills it with random integers between 1 and 100.  The program then outputs the largest and the smallest integers in the array.

This is what I have so far:

```
public class LargestSmallest
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int [] number = new int [2];
        System.out.println ("The random numbers generated are: ");
        for (int count =0; count < number.length ; count++)
        {
            number[count] = (int)(Math.random()*100+1);
            System.out.println (number[count]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: finding and outputting the smallest and the largest numbers.

Comment: well lol sorry that was just for me to run it faster that's all.

Comment: Where the code where you tried to do that?

Comment: aren't you talking about  the size of my array, which is 2? I  did that to make things simple, but i cant figure out how to output the smallest and the largest so really there is no point.

Comment: You're hurting yourself by posting this without showing what you've tried first (or without trying something first). Come on -- don't do this to yourself.

Comment: guys any suggestions?

Comment: the thing is what I've tried looks pretty stupid.

Comment: But you're not likely to get help then, especially if your not open to *any* solution. Adding the code is going to be the first step in getting help.

Comment: to find the min and max (a.k.a completing the tutorial exercise), you have to follow this simple flow chart: 1. write some code, 2. if it doesn't work go back to step 1.

Comment: But  I have no clue of what I have to do next. like I can't think of anything. We learned about arrays today and my teacher really did a bad job on it.

Comment: Then read more tutorials that are easily found online. Search, study, read. If you dump work here, you'll not learn how to get this information on your own, and will be hurting yourself. Seriously.

Comment: How will it help you if we tell you how to do it?

Comment: well I will understand the logics behind it and apply it on other questions I have to do next. :)

Comment: Sure you do. Say it out loud to yourself (seriously); say it a couple times. Identify the steps and write them on a piece of paper. Turn that into pseudo code and check it. Then, write the code to implement it. After you do that and you still have problems, put the code here.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the code, declare a couple of variables to keep track of your minimum and maximum. Set the one keeping track of your minimum to a value that will be higher than any value you will generate (so that the first time it's checked, it will be guaranteed to update) and the one keeping track of the maximum to a value smaller than any value you will generate.

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

As you generate the random numbers, do a quick comparison and update your new numbers.

```
if (number[count] < min)
    min = number[count];
if (number[count] > max)
    max = number[count];
```

Alternatively, if you're required to generate the numbers and THEN find the min and max, write a simple for loop to iterate through the array and do the same thing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    /* Comparison and storage code here */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time mate, but out teacher hasn't  covered "Integer."

Comment: You don't have to use the Integer class, the values just have to be larger and smaller than any number you would generate with the code.

Comment: Or actually, just use the for loop that I suggested (just added an edit like 2 minutes ago if you haven't seen it yet) and set the initial values of min and max to the first element of the array.

Comment: why the first element?

Comment: Because the first element is guaranteed to be a value that you produced. Anything bigger or smaller later on in the array will replace it, and if there is nothing to replace it later, it's already the largest/smallest value you have.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for your random function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] number = new int[100];
    System.out.println("The random numbers generated are: ");
    for (int count = 0; count < number.length; count++)
    {
        number[count] = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
        System.out.println(number[count]);
    }
    int min = 101;
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++)
    {
        if (number[i] < min)
        {
            min = number[i];
        }
        if (number[i] > max)
        {
            max = number[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Max:" + max);
    System.out.println("Min:" + min);
}
```